# How do I define how much HTTP connections an Axis2c client should use?

Tags: apache, axis2c

I have a server and client, which communicate with Soap requests. The client is a C++ application, using [Axis2c](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/) 1.6.0.

In the axis options the default HTTP timeout is 30 sec. However, I need to send request every 3 seconds and this generates too much HTTP connections on the server.

There are 40+ HTTP connections opened and "Waiting" and just one "Connected".

How can I reduce those? Can I somehow tell axis2c to reuse connections? Or in other words, if the response is received before the timeout, why this connections stays open for 30 seconds??

Comment: No answer for more than a week, despite the bounty. This could mean 3 things:
(1) I've asked unclear question
(2) The bounty is too low (sorry, I don't know how can I increase a running bounty)
(3) Nobody cares about axis2c

I assume the last and will probably stop using this library.

Comment: Add a link to axis2c. I never heard about it. Also, sockets stuff depends on how the OS handles things. By the way, what OS are you using?

Comment: The OS is 64 bit Windows. It behaves exactly the same way on XP, 7, or 2003 whatever edition.

Comment: By the way I don't think the bounty is too low. But your best chance for a bounty hunter to answer begins in 12 hours or so.

Comment: The bounty didn't help... Then I consider this library as 'dead' and replace it with something else. Btw, this is the first time since I'm using stackoverflow with no answer after 2 weeks!

Comment: Yeah!  That would make me consider a library dead too, for practical purposes. Even 8088 related questions gets answers here quickly.